# Installing public certificate from amazon certificate manager on a centos server

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, ssl

I have generated a public certificate for my domain.
It all works fine, but my couchdb database installed on an A2 VPS instance (CentOS) needs the certificate too. I manage the DNS with route 53 to map my server IP to db.tagidea.net.

How do I get the certificate installed on the server so that I can access db.tagidea.net over SSL?

Comment: You need to change CouchDB to authenticate via SSL.

Comment: You cannot use Amazon issued certificates on non AWS managed services. These certificates are only meant for ALB, CloudFront, etc. The issue is that Amazon will not provide you with the private key for these certificates.